# Disable "Save" button after condition on Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-components

Hi I'm new to Salesforce and am stuck on this part:

How to disable the "save" button after it was already clicked?

My Component:

```
<div align="right"> 
   <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Salvar" onclick="{!c.Save}" />
</div>
```

My Controller

```
Save: function (component, event, helper) {
    console.log('helper.Salvar');
    helper.Salvar(component, event, helper);
    console.log('helper.Salvar');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this:-

```
Save: function (component, event, helper) {
    let button = event.getSource();
    button.set('v.disabled',true);
}
```

This uses event.getSource() to get the source component that fired this component event and later set the value.

Read here:- [Handling Events with Client-Side Controllers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_client_side_controller.htm)

Comment: It worked!!

Thanks Sanket Kumar ;)